# Django model field validators doesn't work at all

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I can't figure out why my validators doesn't work at all.

1. Form is not invalid
2. Model doesn't raise `ValidationError` when being saved

For input: "123456sdad"

I have a model which has `broker_ico` field:

```
REGEX_ICO = r"\d{6,8}"

broker_ico = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='IČO',
                              validators=[RegexValidator(REGEX_ICO)])
```

I've overwritten save method:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    print('full clean')
    self.full_clean()
    super().save(**kwargs)
```

Moreover the `form` is a `ModelForm`:

```
class BusinessCaseDocumentForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BusinessCaseDocument
        exclude = ['id','business_case']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BusinessCaseDocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            fs_helpers.add_widget_attribute('class', 'form-control', field)
```

UpdateView:

```
class BusinessCaseDocumentUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = BusinessCaseDocument
    form_class = BusinessCaseDocumentForm
    template_name = "business_cases/businesscase_documents/create.html"
    success_message = "Podklad k obchodnému prípadu bol upravený"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['businesscase'] = self.object.business_case  # TODO self.businesscase set
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("business_cases:list")
```

Can you see where is the problem?

Comment: Well your regex says that it should contain a sequence of six to eight numbers, but it does not say that that is the full string.

Comment: It is however probably useful to specify *what input* you enter and is not giving the right response.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh, man, thanks! :D So I should be something like: ^\d{6,8}$

Comment: indeed. Now `bla01234567` would be accepted, with `^\d{6,8}$`, only `012345`, etc. are accepted (so no `bla`).